# How to select value from select list

Tags: watir-webdriver

I tried to choose value from select list.
I used code:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'isc_2W').select 'Animal'
```

but my solution doesn't work.

Site where you can find select-list:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tile_filtering

[image: Select list]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first at all it's doesn't select-list, just style like select-list, but, we can do it:

```
browser.element(:xpath, '//*[@id="isc_2Y"]').click
browser.element(:text, 'Animal').click
```

Comment: Script found a element "Animal", but nothing has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select the value using the label of the dropdown value, not the value itself.

Try

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'isc_2W').select_value "Animal"
```

or the updated syntax:

```
browser.select_list(id: 'isc_2W').select_value "Animal"
```